2nd order Fermi's Golden rule and Rayleigh scattering
In the second order Fermi's golden rule, the amplitude of the final state $|n\rangle$ with an initial state $|i\rangle$ is given by:
\begin{equation}
c_n^{(2)}=\frac{i}{\hbar}\sum_m \frac{V_{nm}V_{mi}}{E_m-E_i}\int_0^t dt' (e^{i\omega_{ni}t'}-e^{i\omega_{nm}t'})
\end{equation}
In Sakurai's QM book, it was argued that as time becomes large the first term in the bracket will give a term like $\delta(\omega_{ni})$, which will give rise to a transition rate, for the same reason as in first order Fermi's golden rule. However, I'm not sure why the second term can be simply neglected since it is very possible that we have an intermediate state $|m\rangle$ that has energy close to the energy of the given final state.
I will give an example. Consider a quantum treatment of Rayleigh scattering. We have an incident photon with $|\vec{k},\hat{\epsilon}\rangle$ as the wave vector and polarization (frequency is $\omega$). It interacts with an atom in the ground state $|g\rangle$. For Rayleigh scattering, the photon is off-resonant. The final state should be the atom back in the ground state while we have another photon with $|\vec{k}',\hat{\epsilon}'\rangle$ (frequency is $\omega'$). The evolution of the system has a path like this: the atom first absorbs the original photon and it jumps to the excited state $|e\rangle$, and then it emits the new photon at $|\vec{k}',\hat{\epsilon}'\rangle$ and returns to the ground state. For this process, the first term in the 2nd order Fermi's golden rule tells us that the transition rate contains $\delta(\omega'-\omega)$, which means that the scattered photon should have the same energy as the incident photon. This is what we expect for Rayleigh scattering. However, in the second order perturbation theory, there is also a possibility that there is a significant transition rate when $\omega_{nm}=0$. For our example, this means that the emitted new photon can have a frequency $\omega_{eg}$, which is the resonant frequency of the atom. This seems to be unphysical as it would violate energy conservation since we only injected an off-resonant photon. However, I fail to see how to reject this possibility when looking at the equation.
